# Trigger notification based on minor or major version

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, alert

## What I have:

- SharePoint Online
- Site Owner level permissions
- SharePoint Designer Access
- Library A

Is there a way to trigger an email notification based on changes to the minor and major versions of a document?

### Example

Document 1 in list A changes from version 5.0 to 5.1. I'd want to send an email to some users.

When document 1 in List A changes to a major release, I'd want to notify all users.

### Notes

The notifications that can be configured for the library offer general notifications of if something was changed. As far as I understand, these notifications do not delineate between minor and major versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the alerts on the document library then select the appropriate settings.

- **Change Type** : select what type of change you want to get alerts
- **Send Alerts for These Changes:** over here you can select what type of changes you want to select.

[image]

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. Let me edit my post and see if I can clarify. Thanks though! @Waqas_Sarwar